# Is there a limit on working with matrix in R with Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp

I was trying to develop a program in R to estimate a Spearman correlation with Rcpp. I did it, but it only works with matrix with less of a range between 45 00 - 50 000 vectors. I don't know why, but it only works with that dimension. I suppose there's  limit with that type of information, maybe if I work it like a data.frame? I would really appreciate if someone gives me insight.

Here i post my code. Ive been trying to limit the max integer number that i call "denominador", which exceeds it. Maybe you could help me.

```
cppFunction('double spearman(NumericMatrix x){
 int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();
 int nrow1 = nrow - 1;
 double out = 0;
 double cont = 0;
 double cont1 = 0;
 double r = 0;
 int denominador = ncol*(pow(ncol,2.0)-1)

 for(int i = 0; i < nrow1; i++){
 #Here i use every combination of vectors starting with the first one, and so on
  for(int j = i +1; j < nrow; j++){
   cont1 = 0;
   for(int t = 0; t < ncol; t++){
    cont = pow(x(i,t)-x(j,t), 2.0);
    cont1 += cont;
   }
   #Here i begin to store the mean correlation, in order to a final mean of all the possible correlations
   r = 2*(1-6*(cont1/denominador))/(nrow*nrow1);
   out += r;
  }
 }
 return out;
}')
```

Comment: Matrices are limited because they must have number of elements less than `.Machine$integer.max`

Comment: But, as i said, my matrix has less than 45 000 vectors. Or are u refering to the number of elements of the matrix?

Comment: I see, there´s a limit working with matrix :(
Any suggestion?

Comment: @L.Vaiz without providing code, we cannot really help outside of what I posted below.

Comment: @42:  R 3.0.0 overcame that (on 64-bit systems).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To repeat more succintly:

1. You can have more than 2^31-1 elements in a vector.
2. Matrices are vectors with `dim` attributes.
3. You can have more than 2^31-1 elements in a matrix (ie `n` times `k`)
4. Your row and column index are still limited to 2^31.

Example of a big vector:

```
R> n <- .Machine$integer.max + 100
R> tmpVec <- 1:n
R> length(tmpVec)
[1] 2147483747
R> newVec <- sqrt(tmpVec)
R>
```

Comment: I fear that there is still not an answer to the question posed. Neither the earlier limits nor the current limits would explain why the OP is getting problems when exceeding a "matrix with less of a range between 45 00 - 50 000 vectors".

Comment: Working code or the questions doesn't exist. OP failed that.  BTW, your initial comment to him is also on the wrong side of true.

Comment: Ive just put the code. I think the problem is in the (nrow*nrow1), because for a 50 000 vectors matrix, it would exceed the max integer number??

Comment: You put it **in the wrong place**.  Edit your question.  Delete the non-answer you added.

Comment: Did it. The code is in the original post. Please check it!

Answer (score 6):

## A couple caveats

Before we get started, I'm assuming:

- `R > 3.0.0`

  - [Long Vectors](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html) that allow for 2 ^ 52 elements are then supported
- `Rcpp > 0.12.0`

  - Patch where thirdwing replaced instances of `int` and `size_t` with `R_xlen_t` and `R_xlength`. [See release post for more details...](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2015/07/25/)

## Constructing a large `NumericMatrix`

I think you may be running into a memory allocation issue...

As the following works on my 32gb machine:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericMatrix make_matrix(){
                   NumericMatrix m(50000, 50000);
                   return m;
                  }")

m = make_matrix()

object.size(m)

## 20000000200 bytes # about 20.0000002 gb
```

Running:

```
# Creates an 18.6gb matrix!!!
m = matrix(0, ncol = 50000, nrow = 50000)

Rcpp::cppFunction("void get_length(NumericMatrix m){
                   Rcout << m.nrow() << ' ' << m.ncol(); 
            }")

get_length(m)
## 50000 50000

object.size(m)
## 20000000200 bytes # about 20.0000002 gb
```

## Matrix Bounds

In theory, you are bounded by the total number of elements in the matrix being less than  (2^31 - 1)^2 = 4,611,686,014,132,420,609 per:

> Arrays (including matrices) can be based on long vectors provided each of their dimensions is at most 2^31 - 1: thus there are no 1-dimensional long arrays.

See [Long Vector](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html)

Now, fitting into a matrix:

```
m = matrix(nrow=2^31, ncol=1)
```

> Error in matrix(nrow = 2^31, ncol = 1) :
>    invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In matrix(nrow = 2^31, ncol = 1) :
>
> NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

The limit both *R* and *Rcpp* adhere to regarding the column/row is:

```
.Machine$integer.max
## 2147483647
```

Note that by 1 number we have:

2^31 = 2,147,483,648 > 2,147,483,647 = `.Machine$integer.max`

## Maximum Amount of Elements in a Vector

However, the limit associated with a *pure* **atomic vector** is given as 2^52 (even though it should be in the ballpark of 2 ^ 64 - 1). Thus, we have the following example which illustrates the ability to access 2^32 by concatenating two vectors of 2^31 + 2^31:

```
v = numeric(2^31)
length(v)
## [1] 2147483648

object.size(v)
## 17179869224 bytes # about 17.179869224 gb

v2 = c(v,v)
length(v2)
## 4294967296

object.size(v2)
## 34359738408 bytes # about 34.359738408 gb
```

## Suggestions

1. [Use `bigmemory` via `Rcpp`](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/)
2. Maintain your own stack of vectors.

Comment: Answer was already good (and got my vote), suggestion even better.

Comment: The cited page says max number of elements is 2^52 (not 2^64-1)

Comment: @42- Aye, meant to say it should be the other way. Thanks.