# RcppEigen cannot return matrix to R with more than 2^31 elements

Tags: r, rcpp

I've been using the Rcpp and RcppEigen packages to do some matrix calculations and have noticed that an error is produced if the length of the matrix to be returned to R exceeds `.Machine$integer.max`. Here is a reproducible example:

test_rcpp.cpp

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

#include <RcppEigen.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP testM(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> A) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * A.transpose();
    return List::create(Rcpp::Named("first") = C.block(0,0,C.rows()/2,C.cols()),
                      Rcpp::Named("second") = C.block(C.rows()/2,0,C.rows()/2+1,C.cols()));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP testM2(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> A) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * A.transpose();
    return wrap(C);
}
```

test_rcpp.R

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("./test_rcpp.cpp")

A <- matrix(rep(1, ceiling(sqrt((.Machine$integer.max)))), nrow=ceiling(sqrt(.Machine$integer.max)))

tm <- do.call(rbind, testM(A))

tm2 <- testM2(A)
```

Running `testM2(A)` returns an error `Error in testM2(A) : negative length vectors are not allowed`. Currently, `testM(A)` is my workaround, which splits the matrix in half and returns a list of the two halves.

Is this intended behavior? And if so, what other workarounds are there?

This [link](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/459) had some information but didn't help me specifically with this problem. A similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757326/is-there-a-limit-on-working-with-matrix-in-r-with-rcpp) suggests problems are encountered when the dimensions of the matrix exceed 2^31. In this case, the matrix I'm returning has dimension `c(46341, 46341)`, well under the 2^31 limit imposed on matrix indices, and contains 2147488281 elements, well under the 2^52 limit imposed on `long` vectors.

A subset of `sessionInfo()` information:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

Note: I get the same problem on R version 3.4.2.

Comment: I have an error with `tm <- do.call(rbind, testM(A))`: `Error in testM(A) : std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: This is most likely due to exhausting memory. How much RAM do you have available?

Comment: System is 16 GB. Available atm is 10 GB.

Comment: This matrix (on my machine) is 46341x46341 in size, requiring about 16GB of memory, so I'd say you're running out of memory when calling testM(A).

Comment: You can halve the required memory by using an integer matrix. Anyway, this seems more like an RcppEigen than an Rcpp issue, since passing the matrix as Rcpp::IntegerMatrix works.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll amend the title.

Comment: I've updated the last paragraph giving my reasoning for why this isn't a duplicate. If I've missed something (or messed something up) please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation in the current implementation of RcppEigen. Example:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]    
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void get_length_rcpp(Rcpp::IntegerMatrix m){
  Rcpp::Rcout << m.nrow() << ' ' << m.ncol() << ' ' 
              << (m.nrow() * m.ncol()) << ' ' << m.size(); 
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void get_length_eigen(Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXi> m){
  Rcpp::Rcout << m.rows() << ' ' << m.cols() << ' ' 
              << (m.rows() * m.cols()) << ' ' << m.size(); 
}

/*** R
N <- 5e4
A <- matrix(1L, ncol = N, nrow = N)
get_length_rcpp(A)
get_length_eigen(A)
*/
```

Output:

> ```
> > N <- 50000
>
> > A <- matrix(1, ncol = N, nrow = N)
>
> > get_length_rcpp(A)
> 50000 50000 -1794967296 2500000000
> > get_length_eigen(A)
> Error in get_length_eigen(A) : 
>   long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:519
> Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> get_length_eigen -> .Call
> Execution halted
> ```

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/issues/54) and a [pull request](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/pull/55) on github for this.